# Ubuntu 13.10 to LG TV via HDMI

Tags: 13.10, ati, graphics, hdmi, tv

I am unable to connect a Ubuntu 13.10 box to a 55 LG LED 1080p 240 HZ smart tv (model #55LAS400) via HDMI. Sometimes I just get a green screen on the TV or other times it won't recognize the TV at all.

Connecting to a ASUS monitor via HDMI or VGA works no problem, so I know the cable is OK. I am using a ATI Radeon 5450 HD graphics card and this problems occurs with both the open source X.Org and fglrx catalyst drivers.

[The HDMI page on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HDMI) discusses that the TV HDMI modelines are faulty. I tried the DVI approach:

> If your television has a separate DVI port, you can try connecting to
>   that (try replacing the HDMI->HDMI cable with an HDMI->DVI cable, with
>   the DVI end hooked to the TV, and HDMI on the computer). If you're
>   able to get a valid signal there, take note of its modeline and try
>   that with the HDMI->HDMI connection. Over DVI, the TV sometimes will
>   report a non-interlaced native resolution the video driver can handle.

This is the output of ''xrandr --verbose'' when both the HDMI (HDMI-0) and VGA (VGA-0) are hooked up to the LG TV but having the TV use the VGA input. In this configuration, the TV does not even recognize the HDMI input, however Ubuntu recognizes that HDMI-0 is connected.

```
steambox@steambox-MS-7786:~$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x53
    Timestamp:  3054999
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6d010001010101
        0116010380a05a780aee91a3544c9926
        0f5054a1080031404540614071408180
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500a05a0000001e662150b051001b30
        40703600a05a0000001e000000fd003a
        3e1e5310000a202020202020000000fc
        004c472054560a202020202020200143
        02032ef1489022200504030201230957
        0778030c004000802d20c00e014f00fe
        08100610181028103810e3050301023a
        801871382d40582c4500a05a0000001e
        011d8018711c1620582c2500a05a0000
        009e011d007251d01e206e285500a05a
        0000001e263680a070381f4030202500
        a05a0000001a00000000000000000034
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: offonauto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x57)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x59)  148.4MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.4KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   59.9Hz
  1920x1080 (0x2ed)  138.6MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock   66.6KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1082 end 1087 total 1111           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080i (0x5a)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.8KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.1Hz
  1920x1080 (0x2ee)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.8KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   30.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x2ef)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock   27.0KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   24.0Hz
  1920x1080i (0x5c)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.7KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x2f0)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.7KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   30.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x2f1)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock   27.0KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   24.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5f)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1360x768 (0x2f2)   85.5MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1424 end 1536 total 1792 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  795           clock   60.0Hz
  1152x864 (0x2f3)   81.6MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock   53.7KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x64)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x66)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   59.9Hz
  1024x768 (0x6a)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x70)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  720x480 (0x73)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  720x480 (0x74)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  640x480 (0x77)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  640x480 (0x2f4)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  640x480 (0x78)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  720x400 (0x79)   28.3MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock   70.1Hz
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x54
    Timestamp:  3054999
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    load detection: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: offonauto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
VGA-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x57) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
    Identifier: 0x55
    Timestamp:  3054999
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6d010001010101
        0116010368a05a780aee91a3544c9926
        0f5054a1080031404540614071408180
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500a05a0000001e662150b051001b30
        40703600a05a0000001e000000fd003a
        3e1e5310000a202020202020000000fc
        004c472054560a20202020202020005c
    load detection: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x57)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5f)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1360x768 (0x2f2)   85.5MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1424 end 1536 total 1792 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  795           clock   60.0Hz
  1152x864 (0x2f3)   81.6MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock   53.7KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x6a)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x70)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  640x480 (0x77)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  640x480 (0x2f4)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  720x400 (0x79)   28.3MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock   70.1Hz
steambox@steambox-MS-7786:~$
```